# Formulario com Ajax / Json / PHP

Tags: php, html, ajax, json

tudo bem ? será que poderiam me ajudar com o seguinte problema.

Vejo varias pessoas falando em criação de formularios com Json / Ajax e tudo mais , mas tipo , sou muito por fora disso ainda.

Mas me surgiu a necessidade de elaborar um formulario da seguinte forma.

O formulario teria 2 combobox ( dropdown )

- 1º Combobox : OPÇÃO 1 , OPÇÃO 2

e um segundo combobox que seria preenchido de acordo com o primeiro combobox .

Caso o 1º combobox seja OPÇÃO 1 , então o segundo combobox iria carregar o item "SERVICO1" , caso o combobox seja OPÇÃO 2 , então o segundo combobox iria carregar o item "SERVIÇO2".

Alguem poderia me ajudar , prometo que irei utilizar apenas como estudo .

Comment: Qual código está a tentar e qual o ponto que está encontrando dificuldade ?

Answer (score 0):

Thiago, sua pergunta não está muito clara. Você colocou Ajax / Json / PHP no título, mas, se entendi bem, parece que não precisa nada disso.

Vou descrever os cenários mais comuns e você vê em qual se encaixa melhor.

Em todos os casos, você vai precisar de uma função cujo `trigger` será o evento `change` do primeiro Select.

**Cenário 1:** Quando carrega seu formulário, você já tem os dados do primeiro e do segundo Select.

Quando o primeiro select foi alterado, sua função irá verificar a opção selecionada e define o valor do segundo Select.

**Cenário 2:** Quando carrega seu formulário, você tem os dados do primeiro Select, mas os dados do segundo dependem da opção escolhida no primeiro.

Aqui você tem 2 possíveis soluções:

1. Carregar dois conjuntos de opções para o segundo Select e, na sua
   função que captura o evento `change`, você define o conjunto de opções
   para o segundo Select.
2. Carregar apenas as opções do primeiro Select.
   No evento `change`, sua função faz um Ajax que carrega as opções e
   monta o segundo Select.

Esses são os cenários mais comuns que vejo acontecer. Se puder especificar melhor qual a sua situação, posso detalhar mais.